# Caching ActiveStorage images in background jobs / PDF documents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I generate PDF tickets using Prawn, and I will, for example, insert an active storage image like this:

```
def image_data(attachment)
  StringIO.new attachment.download
end
```

`image image_data(ticket_template.background)`

But I noticed that some customers have many tickets, and they all use the same image. ActiveStorage is downloading the image every time from S3, so if a customer has like 10 tickets, it could lead to a timeout when downloading all of them.

I am on heroku, so even though the file system is not permanent, I thought it would be a good idea to use the disk cache to fetch or download images as needed. But I'm nervous about adding caching and causing issues.

I thought of adding a lib class such as this:

```
class ImageCacher

  def self.get(record, attachment)
    ## fetch from disk, or download from S3
  end

end
```

Looking for tips and ideas on implementing this.

Comment: How did you solve this?